# Hi, I wondered if anyone knows the model and maybe the age of my Dahon folding Bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: Sticker on Frame]I wondered if anyone knows the model and maybe the age of my Dahon folding Bike as pictured below.

I'm having trouble with both of the Quick Releases on the hinges and it might help me obtain replacements.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

[image: Dahon Folding Bike]

[image: Quick release]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  While knowing more about the history might help a bit finding replacements, it's often the case for older bikes that it's easier to find compatible parts than OEM parts.  You should include close-up photos of the parts you want help finding; people might be able to help directly with that.

Comment: What makes you think its a Dahon - is there a sticker?   I've never seen a diamond frame folder from Dahon, because they are all single-member designs.   https://www.google.com/search?q=dahon+folding+bike&tbm=isch
Can you please use [edit] to add photos of your QR locks and what's not working there - the brand and age are mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Criggie, Thanks for your comment, much appreciated. I've added a photo of the Dahon sticker that is on the bike and also the Quick release.

Comment: Hi DavidW, Thanks for your comment, I had assumed components like this would be made by the bike manufacturer. I've added a photo of the Quick Release (removed from the bike).

Comment: I'm guessing you're in the UK?     BS6102 is uniquely a British Standard.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be similar to some of the bikes marketed as Dahon "Mountain Classic", perhaps from the late 1990s, judging by similarity to image search results.

Comment: Thanks Miff, I googled Dahon Mountain Classic and found a photo of one very similar to mine, even down to the QR levers. It had front suspension and possible seat suspension which mine hasn't but I still think you're correct.

Comment: @pebbleridge based on the colour of your fork, its been replaced at some time.

Answer (score 0):

That QR looks a bit beefier than a regular QR one might find on a seatpost clamp, so straight-up replacement would have to be a like-for-like part.

The bolt appears a little bent, which may be a contributing factor giving difficulties in operation.  Or it may be camera distortion.

Also, the threads on the bolt look a bit squished. This could be improved with a suitable Die that matches the thread diameter and pitch.

The release lever will operate on a cam, and if that's stiff to move then cleaning and lubricating might be all it needs.  Any surface dings in the contact faces should be filed or stoned off where possible.

Lastly, that nut looks a bit beaten up.  I expect its some kind of castellated nut that fits bosses on the frame to prevent rotation, but it has been chewed up over time?
The fix here is a replacement nut, with the same thread specs as the bolt.  It may be workable to fit two regular nuts, get the first in the right place and jam the second nut against it.

Comment: Hi Criggie, Thanks for your suggestions. The issue with the QR is that it doesn't seem to do anything, but I don't understand why. Obviously the nut is chewed up, but it still screws in and out. but if you tighten it the release doesn't release at all and if you loosen it,  then it doesn't lock. So instead of being a quick release it's a manual one. The lever itself is free to move. You are correct, we are in the UK.

Comment: P.S sorry for the delay replying, I haven't figured out how to activate notifications.